# I can't copy a folder to my USB drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1

I have an 8 GB USB drive.  When I tried copying a folder of 90 MB with 4 files, it becomes unresponsive (`Not Responding` is displayed). I have to go to Task manager to end the task.

It is not write protected in any way.  I can create a folder and then copy my files individually to that folder. Also, I can copy files back from USB to my Hard drive.

Details of my USB drive:

Files System : NTFS 
Free Space Available: 7.03 GB

Comment: try running update on computer while USB is plug in

Comment: @Omar Windows Update?

Comment: USB drives should _not_ be NTFS. try backing up your files and reformat it to FAT32

Comment: I tried FAT32 too. Still, I can not copy the entire folder.

Comment: @Omar, If you are mentioning about driver software update, it is upto date and I can copy folders to other USB drive but not to this particularUSB. I am using a new USB now but I want to know what went wrong with my Old one.

Comment: This is an old question.  Did you ever figure it out?  BTW, everybody assumed this was a pendrive because of the size.  However you have a hard drive tag and mention NTFS, which could suggest maybe re-purposing an ancient laptop hard drive or something.  Can you clarify?